# Alternative to rejection sampling for product of probabilities

Tags: probability, algorithms

I have a fixed very large vector $\vec{t} \in (0,1)^n$, which I use as the probability for coinflip outcomes $\vec{c} \in \{0,1\}$. I generate $x_1,\ldots,x_n \sim U[0,1]$ and if $x_i < t_i$ then I set $c_i = 1$, otherwise $c_i = 0$. I have an additional constraint that $\sum_i c_i = m$, so if the outcomes do not have $m$ ones, then I repeat the process until $\sum_i c_i = m$ is satisfied. This is a special case of rejection sampling and then the vector $\vec{c}$ is sampled with probability $p(\vec{c})$ proportional to $q(\vec{c})=\prod_{i=1}^n c_i t_i + (1-c_i) (1-t_i)$, more precisely:

$$p(\vec{c}) = \frac{q(\vec{c})}{\sum_{r\in\{0,1\}^n, |r|=m}q(\vec{r})}$$

The space is so large, that I cannot compute the probabilities of all $r\in\{0,1\}^n$ such that |r| = m and sample from this, so I am using rejection sampling. This is quite inefficient however, as I have to generate all $x_1,\ldots, x_n$, threshold, check $\sum_i c_i = m$, and repeat that until I get an outcome with $\sum_i c_i = m$. Is there a more efficient method that results in the same probability?

Comment: Your question is related to sampling from Fisher's noncentral hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: @PeterO. Thank you very much! I wouldn't have found this without you. It seems my problem is a special case of the multivariate one with the classes containing only a single item. I found a paper for sampling from those too: https://www.agner.org/random/nchyp2.pdf If you have any references you would suggest I would have a look at those too. Feel free to make your comment an answer, since it basically answers my question, because there seems to be a lot of literature on sampling Fisher's noncentral hypergeometric distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is related to sampling from Fisher's noncentral hypergeometric distribution, with $n$ items each assigned its own color.  A random variate with this distribution expresses the number of items of each color, each item being sampled independently with a separate probability $t_i$, given that $m$ items out of $n$ are sampled.

Agner Fog discusses this distribution, as well as sampling algorithms, in the following publications:

- [Sampling Methods for Wallenius' and Fisher's Noncentral Hypergeometric Distributions](https://www.agner.org/random/nchyp2.pdf).  See also *Communications in Statistics—Simulation and Computation* 37 (2008).
- [Biased Urn Theory](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BiasedUrn/vignettes/UrnTheory.pdf).